# Memory Leaks Issue in Protocol involving Mirror

Tags: ios, swift, memory, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I wrote this protocol so that I could create a struct and convert it by accessing this method:

```
protocol JSONConvertable {
    func toAnyObject() -> Dictionary<String, Any>
}

extension JSONConvertable {
    func toAnyObject() -> Dictionary<String, Any> {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        var dict = Dictionary<String, Any>()
        for child in mirror.children {
            dict[child.label!] = child.value
        }
        return dict
    }
}
```

I'm experiencing the leak on this line:

```
dict[child.label!] = child.value
```

I believe it has to do with the Mirror init but I can't think of a better way to do it.
Thanks!

Comment: maybe your should post your leak description content.

Comment: I'm seeing the same. The object in `child.value` is not ever getting freed, despite the returned dict being used & discarded.